# C# Filter metrotile in panel

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Whats the best way to filter metrotile(button) in a panel. The code i'm trying to use.

```
    if(searchControl1.Controls.ContainsKey(metroTile1.Text))
        {
            metroTile1.Visible = true;

        }else if(!searchControl1.Controls.ContainsKey(metroTile1.Text))
        {
            metroTile1.Visible = false;
        }
        if(searchControl1.Controls.ContainsKey(metroTile2.Text))
        {
            metroTile2.Visible = true;

        }else if(!searchControl1.Controls.ContainsKey(metroTile2.Text))
        {
            metroTile2.Visible = false;
        }
```

I'm using devexpres winforms for the searchcontrol. When i do searchcontrol.Contains, it wants a control instead of a string. So i'm using containskey which it makes where you can't see it, but when i type a contain char. it dosn't show it.

Comment: You mean several statements like this: `metrotile1.Visible = textbox1.Contains(metrotile1.text);`? But that's only code readability, this question is probably just opinion based really.

Comment: Explain, not sure what's your question.

Comment: I updated it, but i'm trying to use the searchcontrol which is like a text box, but made for filter in the devexpress controls. I'm using containskey, but it's not showing the button when contains string.

Answer (score 0):

The control compatible with the SearchControl should implement the ISearchControlClient interface. The list of existing controls implementing this interface is provided in the [DevExpress Documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsSearchControltopic).

If the component that contains metroTile1 and metroTile2 does not implement this interface and you cannot change this component implementation, then your approach is good to hide elements based on the user input.